# Meaning of some errors while hosting django application on Cloud Foundry

Tags: django, cloud-foundry

While trying to host my Django application on Cloud foundry using Gunicorn, my application will be hosted correctly on the URL, but when I see the logs by doing `cf logs <app> --recent` I see some errors:

```
2019-10-18T17:06:36.85+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR [2019-10-18 11:36:36 +0000] [9] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
2019-10-18T17:06:36.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR [2019-10-18 11:36:36 +0000] [9] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8080 (9)
2019-10-18T17:06:36.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR [2019-10-18 11:36:36 +0000] [9] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2019-10-18T17:06:36.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR [2019-10-18 11:36:36 +0000] [68] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 68
```

I want to know what are these errors. And, after these errors also the application is hosted and is up.

Answer (score 0):

None of these are error messages. They are just messages that your application wrote to STDERR. That's all that `[APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR` is telling you. Sometimes apps write error messages to STDERR, sometimes they write other things to STDERR. It just depends on the app.

The log messages look normal and expected. gunicorn is starting, listening on a socket and starting workers. Nothing wrong with that.